# What's the more general case of this puzzler?

Tags: lateral-thinking

There is a puzzle which I remember from many years ago which can be summarised as

> It is easy to arrange 20 items in five rows of four items, but how could you arrange just 10 items in five rows of four items?

The answer is this (spoiler-protected for those of you who want to try to solve it first):

> [image]

which is all very clever, but what is the more general case of this lateral thinking puzzle?

**[edit]**: To clarify what I mean by "general case", I'm not so much asking *whether* there's a general case, but how to describe it, what values are possible, and how to find them.

For example, for an $n$-sided polygon (n>2), each vertex is in two rows of $2$ items, so the *"trivial"* general case is that $n$ items can be arranged in $n$ rows of $2$ if you only count the edges. However, for n>3, each vertex can be joined in $n-1$ rows of $2$ items, producing $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ such rows in total.

Comment: What do you mean general case? I assume that we could generalize this to "How can you make $a$ rows of $b$ using $c$ objects" for some $c < ab$, but I get the feeling that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Shouldn't "four rows of five items" be "five rows of four items"?

Comment: @hvd Good spot - corrected.

Comment: @DennisMeng It's not so much *whether* there's a general case, but how to describe it, what values are possible, and how to find them.

Answer (score 9):

Generally, for any two numbers $(n, k)$, where you want to arrange $n$ coins into rows of $k$, there is some maximum number $m$ of rows that you can arrange them into. We can define this to be $m = f(n, k).$

For $(10, 4)$, you showed that $m = 5$ in your question statement.  Another famous case is $(9, 3)$, in which case the answer is $m = 10$, as follows:

[image: arranging nine coins into 10 rows of three]

Another way you could formulate the problem is to find the minimum number $n$ of coins it takes to form $m$ rows of $k$ coins. Then, we define $g(m, k)$ to equal $n$, and as above, we see that $g(5, 4) = 10$ and $g(10, 3) = 9$.

In each of the above cases, the problem is generalizable in a different fashion, but the two examples given (of the 10 coins in 5 rows of 4 and the 9 coins in 10 rows of 3) are just some of the most well-known ones, probably because they give the most beautiful or symmetric patterns.

Comment: OK, this is pointing towards the general case that I was after.

Comment: @ClickRick, if you know the case you are after, then could you specify you question, please? Otherwise it is completely subjective. This answer 100% perfectly answers on the question in its present formulation.

Comment: @klm123 Congratulations on completely missing my more complete comment in response to Dennis (above), in which I describe more completely what the general case would look like.

Comment: @ClickRick, complete comment is good, but when it (instead of the question itself) contains the whole idea of the question, it is very bad.... nobody has to read comments...